# MarkLogic TDE XPATH not working on repeating group

Tags: xml, xpath, marklogic

I am working with ML version 9.0 and start working with TDE (Template Driven Extraction). I have a lot of XML files ( 3500 xml files of 50 kb each) and load them successfully to ML. I created successful some basic templates (TDE). But when i reach a repeating group of the same element group, the view returns an empty result. The only way is setting the context in a lower level which I don't want because I am not able to select elements form a higher node.

The XML definition below shows an example of an XML file:

```
<scope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <item>
        <transaction>
            <type>CI</type>
            <sscc>00000379471900000025</sscc>
            <location>4260210630688</location>
            <device>VISTALINK.004</device>
            <date>2017-04-25</date>
            <time>02:15:33</time>
            <gmtOffset>+02:00</gmtOffset>
            <actorId>155081</actorId>
        </transaction>
        <order>
            <orderNumber>3794719</orderNumber>
        </order>
        <load>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040019877322</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2062,48707520218</x>
                    <y>2015,24337520512</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548106002</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481060020016434653</grai>
                <column>0</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position/>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040012803719</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2064,20629390666</x>
                    <y>2124,57539157396</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
        </load>
    </item>
</scope>
```

I am already able to select from `/scope/item/transaction/type` and from `/scope/item/order/orderNumber` by applying the following template:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $transactions :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/scope/item</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>transactions</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>transaction/type</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Ordernumber</name>
          <scalar-type>long</scalar-type>
          <val>order/orderNumber</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
return tde:template-insert("Transactions.xml", $transactions)
```

But when I create a new template based on the same structure selecting another level of elements (`/scope/item/load`) it returns an empty view.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $rti :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/scope/item</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>rti_transaction</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>load/rti/grai</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
return tde:template-insert("ssc_rti.xml", $rti)
```

As I mentioned earlier I don't want to change the context because I am not able to select `order` or `transaction` nodes.

I also try with xpath and xquery on 1 xml document to fetch the element. This works fine.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

fn:doc('/transaction/2017-04-25_02-15-33_3794719_00000379471900000025_CI.xml')/scope/item/load/rti/grai/text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Erik's good answer, I'd like to illustrate his comment on denormalizing `item/transaction` and `item/order` values into rows for `item/load/rti`'s.

Load the sample doc into the database with:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/nesting-tde-test.xml",
<scope>
    <item>
        <transaction>
            <type>CI</type>
            <sscc>00000379471900000025</sscc>
            <location>4260210630688</location>
            <device>VISTALINK.004</device>
            <date>2017-04-25</date>
            <time>02:15:33</time>
            <gmtOffset>+02:00</gmtOffset>
            <actorId>155081</actorId>
        </transaction>
        <order>
            <orderNumber>3794719</orderNumber>
        </order>
        <load>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040019877322</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2062,48707520218</x>
                    <y>2015,24337520512</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548106002</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481060020016434653</grai>
                <column>0</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position></position>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040012803719</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2064,20629390666</x>
                    <y>2124,57539157396</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
        </load>
    </item>
</scope>)
```

If you then try to run a TDE template with `item` as context, it will fail:

```
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $doc := doc("/nesting-tde-test.xml")
let $template :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>item</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>transactions</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>transaction/type</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Ordernumber</name>
          <scalar-type>long</scalar-type>
          <val>order/orderNumber</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>rti</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>load/rti/grai</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
let $_ := tde:validate($template)
return try {
  tde:node-data-extract($doc, $template)
} catch ($e) {
  $e/error:format-string/data()
}
```

The above returns:

> Eval for Column rti='load/rti/grai' returns multiple nodes (only one is expected)

You can however change context to use `item/load/rti`, and then access ancestors using `parent::` or `ancestor::` axes, or the parent abbrev `..`:

```
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $doc := doc("/nesting-tde-test.xml")
let $template :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>item/load/rti</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>transactions</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>../../transaction/type</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Ordernumber</name>
          <scalar-type>long</scalar-type>
          <val>../../order/orderNumber</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>rti</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>grai</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
let $_ := tde:validate($template)
return tde:node-data-extract($doc, $template)
```

The latter returns:

```
{
    "/nesting-tde-test.xml": [{
        "row": {
            "schema": "main",
            "view": "transactions",
            "data": {
                "rownum": "1",
                "type": "CI",
                "Ordernumber": 3794719,
                "rti": "8003087145481860040019877322"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "row": {
            "schema": "main",
            "view": "transactions",
            "data": {
                "rownum": "2",
                "type": "CI",
                "Ordernumber": 3794719,
                "rti": "8003087145481060020016434653"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "row": {
            "schema": "main",
            "view": "transactions",
            "data": {
                "rownum": "3",
                "type": "CI",
                "Ordernumber": 3794719,
                "rti": "8003087145481860040012803719"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply i am now on vacation with my family. So i hope you accept the delay in commiting and testing the answer!

Answer (score 5):

To generate multiple rows from a single document, the context for the template must match an element (or JSON property) in the repeated substructure.

In this case, the template would likely match rti.

The value expression for a template can have an upward relative path, so you are able to produce columns in the detail with values from the master structure that contains the repeated detail substructure.

You can use that capability to insert a foreign key in the detail rows for the related master row (or to denormalize the master data into the detail rows).

In this case, the template might add a foreign key column for the order number.

That's not restrictive because a template document can contain multiple templates that project rows into different views from different parts of the document.

In this case, the container template might use the scope as the context and populate an order scope view with one row per document while a contained template uses rti as the context and and populates an item rti view with multiple rows per document, relating each rti row to the scope row by means of a foreign key to the primary key for the scope row.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks ehenum, for helping explaining. I am understanding it correctly! you say that the context for the RTI view must be set at : "/scope/item/load/rti" and i can refer with a foreign key to the parent view which contains a primary key?

Comment: My understanding of the model is that the orderNumber is the primary key for the scope (the master row).  If that's correct, the template for the rti detail rows can produce a column with the orderNumber as a foreign key.  Then, at query time, the scope row can be joined with the rti rows when appropriate.  Another approach would be to emit all of the scope master values as columns in each of the rti detail rows (that is, denormalize in the index instead of joining on query).